# How can I use USB otg on Intel TV stick?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

I have an intel based TV stick (http://www.geeky-gadgets.com/beelink-pocket-p2-intel-mini-pc-now-available-20-02-2015/) that I want to access it as a mass storage on another windows system.

So in detail: I want to connect this device via a USB cable to another windows 8.1 and see this device as a mass storage on another system.

Can I do this? If yes, how I can setup this system?

Comment: The device is setup to be a USB Host thus accessing its storage unlikely.  Unlike a phone, it has no way to switch modes.

Comment: @Ramhound so what is the point of having a USB OTG on it? It is documented that it has a USB OTG.